# how to revert the result in hashmap key&value in groovy

Tags: list, groovy, hashmap

from the hashmap "hash1", I don't reach to obtain the result "hash2" in groovy:

```
hash1 = [a:['a1','b1','c1'],b:['a1','b1','c1','d1']]

hash2 = [a1:['a','b'],b1:['a','b'],c1:['a','b'],d1:['b']]
```

Can you please Help?

Moris

Comment: What have you tried?  Please share so code, so we can improve on it.

Comment: I want to invert hash key and value so each value in hash1 is changed to be key in hash2.  the keys in hash2 associate the old keys in hash1 as value. It's very important to have the solution. If you need more info, please ask me. e.g. in hash1: a is the key and a1 is the value / in hash2: a1 is the key and a is the value, .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note, I have added a duplicate (a1) in one of the map values to showcase how to eliminate duplicates in case you have them. If you still want to retain duplicates then just remove `.unique()` from the below approach.

```
def map = [a:['a1','b1','c1','a1'],b:['a1','b1','c1','d1']]

map.inject([:].withDefault { [] }) { acc, key, val ->
  val.collect { (acc[it] << key).unique() }
  acc
}

// [a1:[a, b], b1:[a, b], c1:[a, b], d1:[b]]
```

Comment: TIL you can destructure a Map$Entry like this, but not an List

Answer (score 1):

You can collect the reversed tuples of that first map.  Then either group them by first element and collect the lists or just reduce. E.g.:

```
def hash1 = [a:['a1','b1','c1'],b:['a1','b1','c1','d1']]

println(
    hash1.collectMany{ k, vs -> 
        vs.collect{ [it, k] } 
    }.inject([:].withDefault{[]}){ m, t -> 
        m[t[0]] << t[1]; m
    }
)
// => [a1:[a, b], b1:[a, b], c1:[a, b], d1:[b]]
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks a lot!